# Javascript Datetime Time only gives "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime

I want to fill  with only the time (HH:mm) of a Datetime. I have tried a few things but I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". 
My ajax GET call works fine.

```
var id = 0;
var URL = "http://localhost:58510/api/requests/";

onload = function() {
    showRequestDetails();

};

function showRequestDetails() {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var value = query.split("=");
    id = value[1];

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: URL + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            $("#ddArr_txt").val(dateToTime(data.departure_arrivaltime));
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Request by ID failed.');
        }
    });

};

function dateToTime(d) {
    if (d != null) {
        var timeOnly = (d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes());
        return timeOnly;
    }
};
```

GET response example:

```
<Request>
<ID>2</ID>
<departure_arrivaltime>2014-10-29T12:00:00</departure_arrivaltime>
</Request>
```

How can I get only the time in the input field?

Comment: What line of code gives you that error?

Comment: Let's console log the `data.departure_arrivaltime`. What is in it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your `data.departure_arrivaltime` is a string, try converting it to a date before calling `getHours` or `getMinutes` -

```
var d = new Date(data.departure_arrivaltime);
```

Comment: I think this is probably it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.ajax()` call, you indicate that the `dataType` is `json`, yet you are getting XML.  Thus `data` within your success callback is not going to be populated as expected, because it is expecting a JSON string that it can deserialize into `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in this way:

```
$("#ddArr_txt").val(dateToTime(new Date(data.departure_arrivaltime)));
```

The problem is that you are working with a string instead a Date object.